# NodeJS Call GET method within for loop using callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-loop, callback

I am using NodeJS and Express and iterating over an array of strings, for example:

```
  [ "1" , "+" , "B4", "*", "8"]
```

If the string contains a letter, the function should go off and call a GET method to retrieve a value from the Database. My code so far looks like this:

```
function processFormula(formula) {
    console.log(formula)
    var arr = formula.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].match(/[a-z]/i)) {

         /* fetch the value and store it in arr[i] */ 

         }
    return arr.toString();
    }
```

My problem is that the method which goes off to fetch the value takes longer to execute than the processing thread, resulting in

```
undefined
```

cropping up a lot. I am struggling to understand where exactly I should be placing my callback to deal with this situation iteratively?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the first question here for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=frequent . Regarding the loop, have a look at one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+asynchronous+loop

Comment: Thanks Felix for your help

Answer (score 1):

That is tricky to coordinate. You could try using a HTTP request library like `axios` that uses promises. Then, you can use `Promise.all` to coordinate all the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another if inside the for and return until you at the last element:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].match(/[a-z]/i)) {

     /* fetch the value and store it in arr[i] */ 

    }
    if(i == arr.length-1){
            return arr.toString();
    }
}
```

And a suggestion, try using `array.length` outside for loops, because each loop you will be calculating the length of the array to check if condition is achieved, therefore going through array each time. (I didn't change that in my answer). Just do it before the loop and do `var size = array.length`